# Is this supposed to be wordplay/foreshadowing in Kaguya-sama s3? (spoilers)

Tags: manga, anime, jokes, comedy, fiction

**Spoilers for [Kaguya-sama](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Kaguya-sama:_Love_Is_War) s3**

We see that there's this mysterious character that people call 怪盗 (kaitou), which I'm learning is actually a thing in fiction and specifically in Japanese fiction because in the Wikipedia page for [Gentleman thief or phantom thief](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Gentleman_thief) there's like a Japanese translation specifically

> A gentleman thief, gentleman burglar, lady thief, or phantom thief (Japanese: 怪盗, Hepburn: kaitō) is a stock character in fiction.

and even a [whole section](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Gentleman_thief#Phantom_thieves) for 'notable phantom thieves in Japanese popular culture'.

Tonikaku

As it turns out...

> The mysterious character is [Miyuki Shirogane](https://kaguyasama-wa-kokurasetai.fandom.com/wiki/Miyuki_Shirogane), the student council president aka 生徒会長 (Seito kaichō aka Seito kaichou). I notice that kaichou seems to rhyme with kaitou. As far as I understand, it's just changing ch(o) to t(o) or ちょ to と.

Question:

Is this supposed to be some kind of wordplay/foreshadowing that

> the 'kaitou' turns out to be the 'kaichou'

?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It's very unlikely. (I haven't seen the actual episode, though.)

For a reason, the Japanese language has many homophones. 怪盗 and 会長 are both common words, and they don't usually count as a similar-sounding word pair in the first place.

- For かいとう: 怪盗 has many homophones; 解凍 "defrosting", 解糖 "glycolysis", 回答 "answer", 解党 "disbanding of a political party", 開頭 "craniotomy", and so on are all read as かいとう.
- For かいちょう: 会長 also has many; 階調 "gradation", 快調 "in good shape", 怪鳥 "mysterious bird", 海鳥 "ocean bird", 開帳 "exposition" and so on are all read かいちょう.

People who speak a language like this are unlikely to think the similarity of 会長 and 解凍 would serve as a valid wordplay.

Comment: ok thanks naruto. I wasn't able to find any article saying this is a wordplay or something, so you're probably right. Also it's not just 1 episode with 'kaitou'. It's several episodes towards the end. So I don't think you're really missing anything.