# Is this really a joke about initials F.U. ? Wait...do Japanese names have 'initials'?

Tags: manga, names, anime, jokes, comedy

Based on the [Kaguya-sama case](https://japanese.stackexchange.com/questions/95191/is-this-supposed-to-be-wordplay-foreshadowing-in-kaguya-sama-s3-spoilers), I guess the answer is negative, but eh [who knows](https://movies.stackexchange.com/questions/104488/what-makes-the-tweety-bird-saw-a-romulan-joke-funny-in-the-original-version)?

---

In Chapter 1 of the manga [The Quintessential Quintuplets](https://japanese.stackexchange.com/questions/93612/the-quintessential-quintuplets-aka-%e4%ba%94%e7%ad%89%e5%88%86%e3%81%ae%e8%8a%b1%e5%ab%81-is-%e5%b1%8a%e3%81%8f%e3%82%93%e3%81%a7%e3%81%99-it-reaches-a-mondegreen), there's a part omitted from the anime where [2 of](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=lpnHsJw_-TI) the quints, [Nino and the female protagonist Itsuki](https://japanese.stackexchange.com/questions/96106/you-cant-address-your-parents-chichi-haha-but-can-you-refer-to-your-parents-as), are talking. Nino calls Itsuki '[niku man obake](https://japanese.stackexchange.com/questions/96137/ghost-monster-%E3%82%AA%E3%83%90%E3%82%B1-vs-%E3%81%8A%E3%81%B0%E3%81%91-but-i-dont-see-the-emphasis)' and says Itsuki won't be '[popular](https://japanese.stackexchange.com/questions/95135/popular-%E3%83%A2%E3%83%86-vs-%E4%BA%BA%E6%B0%97)' with the boys. Itsuki claims to have [recently had lunch with a boy](https://anime.stackexchange.com/questions/66640/why-was-itsuki-about-to-eat-alone-in-the-1st-episode), which is true. The boy is the male protagonist Fuutarou Uesugi.

Nino asks for the boy's name or at least initials. **(See [here for englis](https://i.stack.imgur.com/qw8kG.jpg)h and [here for japanese](https://i.stack.imgur.com/G8M7T.jpg).)**

> 頭文字だけでいいからおしえてー！

which seems to translate to...

> Just the initials are fine, so tell me!

Of course, in English, Fuutarou's initials are [F.U.](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Pv844.jpg) like Frank Underwood from House of Cards.

**Question 1**:

From an English perspective, this is probably a joke where if Itsuki would answer, then it's like Itsuki's telling Nino 'f(- - -) (yo)u'. Is there probably any such kind of joke intended in the [original Japanese](https://movies.stackexchange.com/questions/104488/what-makes-the-tweety-bird-saw-a-romulan-joke-funny-in-the-original-version)? Or if not, then maybe any kind of joke?

- Note: The names [Fuutarou, Raiha](https://anime.stackexchange.com/questions/66730/are-the-uesugi-siblings-f%C5%ABtar%C5%8D-and-raiha-named-after-the-japanese-gods-of-wind), [Isanari](https://anime.stackexchange.com/questions/66807/is-the-dad-isanari-of-the-uesugi-siblings-f%C5%ABtar%C5%8D-and-raiha-named-after-izanami) and Uesugi are chosen for very specific reasons, so all the more probably not. Eh. Then again I don't see why the author Negi Haruba wouldn't instead do the reverse: name the older sibling something that sounds like Raijin and the younger something that sounds like Fūjin.

**Question 2**:

The word for initials appears to be '頭文字'. What exactly are initials in Japanese, and what would be the answer Itsuki would give to Nino? All I can find for Japanese initials are

1. English Wikipedia [Japanese abbreviated and contracted words](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Japanese_abbreviated_and_contracted_words)
2. Japanese Wikipedia initials in katakana I guess - 'inisharu' [イニシャル](https://ja.wikipedia.org/wiki/%E3%82%A4%E3%83%8B%E3%82%B7%E3%83%A3%E3%83%AB)
3. aaaand the street racing anime/manga [Initial D](https://ja.wikipedia.org/w/index.php?search=%E9%A0%AD%E6%96%87%E5%AD%97&title=%E7%89%B9%E5%88%A5:%E6%A4%9C%E7%B4%A2&profile=advanced&fulltext=1&ns0=1&searchToken=80awthuihyxfdssf2wsu256zc).

**Guess based on Link 1:**

ふう as 'initials' for [上うえ杉すぎ 風ふう太た郎ろう](https://5hanayome.fandom.com/wiki/Fuutarou_Uesugi)? I don't see anything up with [ふう](https://en.wiktionary.org/wiki/%E3%81%B5%E3%81%86) or [フウ](https://en.wiktionary.org/wiki/%E3%83%95%E3%82%A6). However...season 2 spoiler

> Fuutarou is given by another quint Miku the nickname ふう or ふう-kun later on. This is the name that Nino refers to Fuutarou by henceforth. I thought ふう comes from the 'ふう' in 'ふうたろう', but apparently it may be based on initials.

- **Edit**: Oh wait wait I just realised...since Japanese names often begin with last names then the initials are actually うふ or ウフ ... or UF....soooo eh? Maybe it's a joke that really relies on the English translation?

Comment: Isn't she just asking for the 頭文字? I don't see any reason to read anything more into it.

Comment: @Leebo So what is the 頭文字 here? ふう  like the 1st hiragana of the 1st name and the 1st hiragana of the last name?

Comment: @Angelos Eh sad. Thanks. Post as answer? (Also please explain what exactly '頭文字' is. Like what 1st hiragana of each word?)

Comment: @Angelos No, Japanese people normally use the Hepburn system after graduating from elementary school. See [this official page](http://www.tbs.co.jp/anime/5hanayome/2nd/character/index.html).

Comment: @naruto so what system is Angelos referring to? I've heard of the term 'Hepburn' before, but I think it's only now I'm learning there's more than [1 system for romanisation](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Romanization_of_Japanese#Modern_systems).

Comment: @Angelos How come your initials are plural (2 letters U and then H) but in naruto's answer naruto's initials are singular (1 letter U or 1 glyph う)?

Comment: Would you be surprised if I say Fukuoka Airport's airport code (it's used world widely) is FUK? As naruto said, it's just coincidence.

Answer (score 2):

**Question 1**: You're overthinking again. No such joke is intended. If his initials have some strange meaning in another language, that is purely a coincidence.

**Question 2**: イニシャル and 頭文字 are a little different. イニシャル in Japanese is a word that almost specifically refers to the first **Latin** character of a **person name** (in his case, "U"). 頭文字 refers to the first character in general, and it can be the first kanji ("上"), the first kana ("う"), or the first romaji ("U") of anything. Since 上 is obviously too specific as a hint, so I'd expect う or U as a response. (Technically, 風/ふ/F can be called his 頭文字, too, but remember Itsuki is a type of character who keeps addressing him with his family name.)

Comment: 1 - As for overthinking... [Is it ok to overanalyze an anime?](https://anime.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/4509) like [this](https://anime.stackexchange.com/q/66802#comment79235_66802) ? 2 - ok thanks naruto so what the answer for イニシャル is just the *single* letter U and the answer for 頭文字 is the *single* letter(/character?/glyph?) う ? 3 - So 'initials' are actually just *singular* 'initial' ? 4 - So what's going on in [this page](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Japanese_abbreviated_and_contracted_words) if the page is not talking about initials?

Comment: @BCLC I don't think you read and understand my answer... Who said "singular"?